# How to use npm with asdf and Nodejs v11 - I get segmentation faults

Tags: npm, segmentation-fault, nvm, asdf

For a new project on my *Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS*, I had to make the switch from `nvm` to `asdf`.

I ran

```bash
nvm deactivate
nvm uninstall 20
nvm uninstall ...[all locally available node versions]
npm unload
```

then installed NodeJS using

```bash
asdf plugin add nodejs https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-nodejs.git
asdf install node latest
asdf global nodejs latest
asdf local nodejs latest
```

It works fine and I have the right `npm` version at hand for almost all NodeJS versions used in different projects.

Bare one: For one very old project, I still need to use `nodejs v11.1.0`. So I ran `asdf install nodejs 11.1.0` and now `asdf` switches to that version whenever I get into that project's directory - respecting my old `.nvmrc` file thanks to the `egacy_version_file = yes` setting in my `~/.asdfrc` file.

But when I want to use `npm`, it always results in a `segmentation fault (core dumped)  npm`.

Before `asdf`, when I used `nvm` with `nvm use` and the proper `.nvmrc` file in that project's directory, `nvm` switched to `npm v6.4.1` and everything worked just fine. Now with `asdf`, I always get that *segmentation fault*  for `npm`, no matter which 11.x version of NodeJS I rtry to install with `asdf`.

`which npm` yields `/home/USER/.asdf/shims/npm`

and `cat /home/USER/.asdf/shims/npm` brings me

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# asdf-plugin: nodejs 20.6.1
# asdf-plugin: nodejs 18.17.1
# asdf-plugin: nodejs 11.1.0
# asdf-plugin: nodejs 11.0.0
# asdf-plugin: nodejs 11.15.0
exec /home/USER/.asdf/bin/asdf exec "npm" "$@"
```

but this doesn't really tell me anything.

I have no idea what's going on there. If anyone could provide me with a hint on how to get a working `npm v6.4.1` running with `asdf` and NodeJS v11.1.0, that would be of great help.

I tried to install that needed npm version using `npm i -g npm@6.4.1` while in another project, as I thought maybe it has to be installed once in that version, but now `asdf` automatically switches to that version of `npm` whenever I am in this other project's directory, and I can't undo it, as now every time I try to run `npm i -g npm@9.6.7`, I get the error that `npm does not support Node.js v18.17.1`, which is the NodeJS version used in that project. So the situation got even worse.

Also, I did not find any relevant article googling for *asdf* and *npm* and *segmentation* fault.